# remove yellow highlight woocommerce order summary

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone knows how to remove the yellow highlight from woocommerce order summary?

Pls take a look at my screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68DOL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could override the style in your CSS sheet. (./style.css)

```
.woocommerce-order strong {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```